# How to show that ${\omega \in \Omega : X(\omega) \neq Y(\omega)}$ is a measurable set, $X,Y$ being $\overline{\mathbb{R}}$-valued.

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

How to show that $\{\omega \in \Omega : X(\omega) \neq Y(\omega)\}$ is a measurable set, $X,Y$ being $\overline{\mathbb{R}}$-valued. I mean, how to fix the case when $X$ and $Y$ = $\infty$? Here i can't pass to the $\{\omega \in \Omega : X(\omega) - Y(\omega) \neq 0\}$ because $\infty - \infty$ isn't defined. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming $X,Y$ are measurable functions.

We need to show that $\{\omega : X(\omega)>Y(\omega)\} = \bigcup_{q\in\mathbb Q}(\{\omega: X(\omega) > q\}\cap\{\omega: Y(\omega) < q\})$ is measurable.

To show this, we only need to notice $\{\omega: X(\omega) > q\}$ and $\{\omega: Y(\omega) < q\}$ are measurable for every $q$, and the set $\mathbb Q$ is countable.

Answer (score 1):

$\{\omega: X(\omega)=\infty, Y(\omega)<\infty\} =\bigcup_n  \{\omega: X(\omega)=\infty\}\bigcap \{\omega: Y(\omega)<n\}$ which is measurable. Simialrly, $\{\omega: Y(\omega)=\infty, X(\omega)<\infty\}$ is measurable. Can you finish?